# Why COOKIES are not accesible from another php page?

Tags: php, cookies

I have two pages add_to_cart.php and index.php.
In add_to_cart.php, I have set the cookie as `setcookie( "add_to_cart", $cookie_value, strtotime( '+2 days'));`, Now I can access this cookie data from the same page where it was created (here add_to_cart.php) but I tried to acess this cookie by using `var_dump($_COOKIE['add_to_cart']);`  from index.php page and an **PHP NOTICE triggered -**

> Notice: Undefined index: add_to_cart
>   I have seen many solution for this problem in *stackOverflow* but nothing fits for me.
>   How can I access cookies from another php pages ?

Comment: Do you have any output before you set the cookie?

Comment: I have already turned on `output buffering` and I am forget to mention that I have set the cookie by AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), the fourth parameter of setcookie contains the path to which the cookie should apply:

> The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If
>   set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If
>   set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/
>   directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. The
>   default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set
>   in.

So set it to `/` and you'll be able to access it from any folder (and page).